# use function on another module linux with EXPORT_SYMBOL

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, driver

I'm trying to execute a function of the linux module that I make. But I don't get success.
This is the [project](https://github.com/GuilhermeGiacomoSimoes/fp_printk)

I created a little function to convert an int to a str float:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/string.h>

#include "service.h"
#include "fp_printk.h"

#define OURMODNAME "fp_printk"

MODULE_AUTHOR("Guilherme Giacomo Simoes <trintaeoitogc@gmail.com>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("This lib will show float-point in printk()");
MODULE_LICENSE("MIT");
MODULE_VERSION("0.4.1");

void fp_printk(int number, int decimal_places, char* destination)
{
    static char buffer[32] = { 0 };
    int buf_index = 30;
    int count_decimal_place = 0;
    int point_include = 0;

    for (; number && buf_index; --buf_index, number /= 10) {
        count_decimal_place++;
        if (!point_include && count_decimal_place > decimal_places) {
            buffer[buf_index] = '.';
            buf_index--;
            point_include = 1;
        }

        buffer[buf_index] = "0123456789"[number % 10];
    }

    strcpy(destination, &buffer[buf_index + 1]);
}

static int __init fp_printk_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s: initial execute module", OURMODNAME);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit fp_printk_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s: module end", OURMODNAME);
}

module_init(fp_printk_init);
module_exit(fp_printk_exit);

EXPORT_SYMBOL(fp_printk);
```

And after converted, copy the str to destination parameter. 
and in my test module, I call:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <asm/fpu/api.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

#include "../fp_printk.h"

MODULE_AUTHOR("Guilherme Giacomo Simoes <trintaeoitogc@gmail.com>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("LKP book:ch5/fp_in_lkm: no performing FP \
(floating point) arithmetic in kernel mode");
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual MIT/GPL");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");

static int __init fp_in_lkm_init(void)
{
    const int number = 1234;
    const int decimal_places = 2;

    char *r = (char*) kmalloc(sizeof("12.34"), GFP_KERNEL);

    printk(KERN_INFO "antes de executar\n");
    extern void fp_printk(number, decimal_places, r);
    printk(KERN_INFO "teste apos a conversao");
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s",r);
    printk(KERN_INFO "teste apos o printk");

    return 0;
}

static void __exit fp_in_lkm_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "removed\n");
}

module_init(fp_in_lkm_init);
module_exit(fp_in_lkm_exit);
```

but when I run sudo dmesg for view printks, I only view:

```bash
[1210228.128703] test_fp_printk: antes de executar
[1210228.128712] test_fp_printk: teste apos a conversao
```

it doesn't print the str r

if I call of fp_printk() in the module_init, it works.

```
static int __init fp_printk_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s: initial execute module", OURMODNAME);
    char *dest = kmalloc(sizeof("12.34"), GFP_KERNEL);
    fp_printk(1243, 2, dest); 
    printk(KERN_INFO, "%s", dest);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `fp_in_lkm_init()` function, you are trying to call `fp_printk()`. Like this:

```
extern void fp_printk(number, decimal_places, r);
```

However, that is not the correct way to call a function. Here, you are just (needlessly) adding a function prototype for the function, not calling it.

You just need:

```
fp_printk(number, decimal_places, r);
```

Note that your test module needs to know about which symbols are exported by your `fp_printk` module. Normally, symbols are available in the `Module.symvers` file that comes with your kernel. But your new symbols won't be available there.

There are a few options, as can be seen in section [6.3 Symbols From Another External Module](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) of the kernel modules documentation. Probably the easiest way for you would be:

> Use an extra Module.symvers file
> When an external module is built, a Module.symvers file
> is generated containing all exported symbols which are
> not defined in the kernel. To get access to symbols
> from bar.ko, copy the Module.symvers file from the
> compilation of bar.ko to the directory where foo.ko is
> built. During the module build, kbuild will read the
> Module.symvers file in the directory of the external
> module, and when the build is finished, a new
> Module.symvers file is created containing the sum of
> all symbols defined and not part of the kernel.

Comment: this not work.  I try this, and i get follow error
```bash
ERROR: modpost: "fp_printk" [/home/simoes/repositories/fp_printk/test/fp_printk_test_e2e.ko] undefined!
```

Comment: Does your `fp_printk.h` file define a prototype like `extern void fp_printk(int number, int decimal_places, char* destination);` ?

Comment: no. Here is my fp_printk.h
```C
#ifndef __FP_PRINTK_H__
#define __FP_PRINTK_H__

void fp_printk(int number, int decimal_places, char* destination);

#endif
```

Comment: Updated answer with some more advice.